# Altium layers "blacked out"

Tags: altium

I have somehow hit a shortcut in Altium that causes all of the layers that I am not currently working on to become grey. I can change layers and they are still there. How do I turn this off? It is not "mask level" of layers feature too. I am in footprint editor if that helps.

Comment: Screenshots or a better description, please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably in single layer mode.  Shift-S toggles it on/off.

Comment: Yeah I was, Jackpot!

Comment: It's a very useful mode, btw.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but that was due to the board being dimmed down. Was fixed by clicking "Mask Level" and then increasing "Masked Objects Factor" in the box "Dim Control".

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to click on the **Clear** button in the bottom far right corner of Altium Designer, next to the *Snap* and *Mask Level* buttons.

[image: Clear Mask Level]

Comment: **Note:** The hotkey for this might be **Shift+C**.